# How to get SharePoint Online list url using Powershell?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, powershell, url

I can retrieve a title `$list.Title`, but a title is not the same as url.

In C# I can get `list.DefaultViewUrl`, which doesn't seem to be an option in Powershell.

I found [this solution](http://www.sharepointed.com/2012/02/17/powershell-get-url-of-sharepoint-list-orlibrary/) with `$List.RootFolder.Url` but it returns empty, so I assume it's not available for SharePoint Online.

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### How to retrieve List Url in SharePoint Online using PowerShell

**CSOM**

```
Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
   $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
   return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
$context.Load($list.RootFolder)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$listUrl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
```

**REST**

SharePoint RESTful web services could be consumed in PowerShell, follow an article [Consuming the SharePoint 2013 REST API from PowerShell](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/04/15/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-powershell/) for a more details.

Endpoint: `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/RootFolder?$select=ServerRelativeUrl`

Example:

```
$Url = $WebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + $listTitle +  "')/RootFolder?$select=ServerRelativeUrl"  
$data = Invoke-RestSPO $Url Get $UserName $Password
$listUrl = $data.ServerRelativeUrl
```

Comment: :) Glad this helped you!